# XLIFF editor which support Santali language?

Tags: translation, language-translation, poedit, xliff

I am finding an editor which can manage translations from English --> Santali but editors like Poedit showing my language as boxes also not this language is not supported by many editors. I have to translate many strings. Is their any editor which support this language. I want to take advantage of Translation memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem. I used windows 8 font changer to change font to Noto Sans Ol Chiki Caption (icon, menu, Message and status) to this font. As windows 8 has no support for Ol Chiki script so i used this application to change my font. Now Poedit is working well supporting Ol chiki font.

Answer (score 0):

Poedit supports any language. If it is showing boxes instead of text, it is because you have configured it, or your operating system, to use a font that lacks the characters. This is not a problem with Poedit or any other editor, but with your fonts and configuration.